# Why the visual system does not affect by the quantum zeno effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, biophysics

According to the quantum zeno effect, if a measurement is done on a sufficiently high frequency, the system remains stationary.

In daily life, human see objects are moving.

(i) Is the procedure when human seeing something a measurement procedure?

(ii) If the answer to question (i) is yes, why human is not affect by the quantum zeno effect? Namely, we still see things move..

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, human senses do not directly interact with the observed objects. When you see a light bulb turn on you observe a result of electron excitation, but your eye does not interact with the electrons in the filament, only with the photons emitted from them. So we're not talking about a quantum "measurement" when we discuss a human watching an object move: this is just the standard, classical Zeno paradox.

When discussing the classical Zeno problem, the issue arises from treating infinities as manageable numbers. The paradox is that as the time difference between two measurements (classically, of position) approaches zero, the position difference between the two measurements also approaches zero; so the change in position between two 'adjacent instants' is effectively zero and thus no motion is possible. However, a value *approaching* zero is not the same as a value *equaling* zero. No matter how small of a time period one measures, the distance covered by a moving object will be proportional to the size of the time period measured, and by definition that proportion is the speed of the object.

The human brain uses the same wetware to collect perceptual data as to process it, so those two aspects operate on the same time scales. If our data processing were much faster than our senses, we'd notice a pronounced Zeno effect: everything would seem in slow motion because we could think about an event much faster than it happens... Like what already happens when you watch grass grow or paint dry. As it is, the sampling rate (i.e. how many times a second data can be collected and processed) of human perception is less than 100Hz (for every sense I'm aware of at least) which in terms of average events is *super duper slow.* Even someone just walking at a normal speed travels a coupled centimeters every 1/100th second, which is considerable. Human perception is not a "sufficiently high frequency" to cause a noticeable Zeno effect in our perception, though if you watch something that is really slow like a plant growing, the effect is quite noticeable.

Comment: How do you characterize/determine the "sampling rate of human perception"?

Comment: You change the frame rate until people can't tell the difference. You measure signal propagation through the optic system in the brain.

Comment: But, theoretically, how do we know the "measurement" in QM sense corresponds to the changing of frame rate until we cannot tell the difference? How do we know what is the measurement corresponds to humans optic system and brain function?

Comment: @user26143 I've expanded the answer considerably: I believe it should answer both of your above comments as well as the original question.

Comment: @Asher Thanks for the expanded answer. That's partially answered by question. However, I still wonder, what is measurement? If I describe the interaction between my eye and photons via a Hamiltonian: $$H_{eye} + H_{photon} + H_{int}$$ and calculate the transition process, I claim it is not a measurement. On the other hand, if the "measurement" is an interaction between system and equipment, I can also try to write a Hamiltonian, $$H_{system} + H_{equipment} + H_{int} $$, this time, the Hamiltonian describes measurement. What is the difference between these two Hamiltonian?

Comment: and what kind of Hamiltonian is for measurement?